# Setting up a particle filter for a deterministic system with stochastic, time-discrete observations

Tags: bayesian, inference, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, particle-filter

I have a deterministic process $x(t)>0$ for $0 < t < T$, governed by an ODE for which I want to do parameter inference in a Bayesian sense. The process is hidden but I have $n$ stochastic observations every time interval $\tau$ ($n = T / \tau$) distributed as a Poisson:

$y(m\tau) \sim Poi\left(\int_{(m-1)\tau}^{m \tau}x(t)dt\right)$

for $m = 1, 2,\dots n$. I model this with an time-varying parameter $\theta(t)$ in the ODE such that it is constant between every pair of observations:

$\theta(t) = \theta_m$ for $(m-1)\tau < t < m \tau$

Currently, I do the inference with Metropolis-Hastings (MH) over the $n$ values of $\theta_m$. I have identical priors and transition rates for all $\theta_m$. I integrate the ODE over the whole span $0<t<T$ and calculate the likelihood analytically from each trajectory $x(t)$.

My issue is this: MH takes MANY iterations to converge and the samples for the last few $\theta_m$'s are autocorrelated unless I thin them out to a very high degree. I am wondering if this could be set up more efficiently using SMC/PMCMC to fit the $\theta_m$'s sequentially in time but I have little experience with these techniques. The fact that the hidden process is deterministic (except for the random $\theta$ from the prior) is throwing me off as I try to follow this book

https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/bayesian-filtering-and-smoothing/C372FB31C5D9A100F8476C1B23721A67

Any insights greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can give my R package a shot: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pfr/vignettes/my-vignette.html